# Possible to set different margin when paragraph has <strong>?

Tags: html, css

```
<p>
la la la la la la
</p>
<p>
<strong>Hello</strong>
<p>
<p>
la la la la la la
</p>
<p>
la la la la la la
</p>
<p>
<strong>Hello</strong>
<p>
<p>
la la la la la la
</p>
```

Having above html. Is it possible with css to achieve this?

```
p {margin-bottom:24px;}
p when having <strong>....</strong> set margin-bottom:5px ?
```

Comment: See my answer (that I figured out thanks to you guys!). Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/g7mux9x0/

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**Update css**

```
p
{
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

p > strong
{
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  display:block;
}
```

[Demo Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/patelsumit5192/hufwe0sb/1/)

Comment: That's not what he meant - he wanted to make a coditional parent selector.

Comment: @Sumit patel Your code adds `margin-bottom` to `<strong>` but when `<p>` has `<strong>` inside then margin should be added to `<p>` not `<strong>`

Comment: If I set p {margin-bottom:50px;} margin bottom of p would be 50px and strong would have a bottom margin of 100px (in your example). I want p to have margin bottom 50px and when p has strong it should have 100px.

Comment: ok.. i once again  answer updated  your requirement .. try it

Comment: I am still wondering how this answer is getting upvotes. Something fishy :D

Comment: Misleading answer. he is not going to set margin for strong.

Comment: hello "Tympaaz", "Faraz Sh"., "Raman Sahasi "see the answer ..  what want to @bestprogrammerintheworld ... read  carefully question & answer all guides

Comment: @Sumitpatel: Based on the question he asked your answer was wrong and we were trying to help you understand it better. We cant really do anything if OP framed the question wrong and you get the answer by fluke. At the end of the day, We all are here to help each other and improve over selves so chill

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot select parents - in this case `p` is parent of `strong` but you can set `strong`'a styles to fit your needs. Also remember that you can set `p` styles to be flexible container of `strong`.

Answer (score 1):

**You can do it with JS**

```js
$(document).ready(function(e){

  $('p').has('strong').css('margin','100px');

});
```

```css
p{ margin:20px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
la la la la la la
</p>
<p>
<strong>Hello</strong>
<p>
<p>
la la la la la la
</p>
<p>
la la la la la la
</p>
<p>
<strong>Hello</strong>
<p>
<p>
la la la la la la
</p>
```

Comment: The question was about pure css but this js solution would actually work. Thank you!

Comment: Not really sure if its possible with CSS but i will keep looking and will let you know if i find it :)

Comment: See my own answer :-)

Comment: Yeah question was wrong :D. I am glad you got it right. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

`P tag` has `margin-bottom` of `24px` and `strong 5px`.

```css
p {
  margin:0px 0px 24px 0px;
  background:#f22;
 }
 strong{
   background:#ccc;
 }
 p > strong{
   display:inline-block;
   margin-bottom:5px;
 }
```

```html
<p>
la la la la la la
</p>
<p>
<strong>Hello</strong>
<p>
<p>
la la la la la la
</p>
<p>
la la la la la la
</p>
<p>
<strong>Hello</strong>
<p>
<p>
la la la la la la
</p>
```